# Use orConditionGroup with query (non entity)

Tags: 8, database

I've used orConditionGroups with queries before. Specifically with entity queries. But now I have a custom sql table I created separate from drupal but still on the same database I have access to. I want to update a row if any of the fields are different but I'm having generating the or statement. Here was my attempt.

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$orConditionGroup = $connection->orConditionGroup()->condition('address', $fulladdress, '!=')->condition('full_name', $fullname, '!=')->condition('telephone', $workphone, '!=');
  $connection->update($table)->fields(['full_name' => $fullname, 'address' => $fulladdress, 'telephone' => $workphone, 'email' => $email])->condition('id', $id)->condition($orConditionGroup);
```

But I get the error

> undefined method
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::condition()

Which makes sense since the connection class isn't a query object on its own, but not sure how else to tackle this. How would I create an orConditionGroup for just a plain direct sql query that isn't a drupal entity or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by added the select method to the connection object like so:

```
$orConditionGroup = $connection->select($table)
                    ->orConditionGroup()
                    ->condition('address', $fulladdress, '!=')
                    ->condition('full_name', $fullname, '!=')
                    ->condition('telephone', $workphone, '!=');
```